# Including static files in a GWT module

Tags: gwt, module

If I have a GWT module that depends on some external static files, is there a way to package these files into the module so that the compiler copies them as static files into the war directory of any project that uses this module?

Comment: When you static files, is it GWT compatible? What I mean is that, do you want these files to be converted into javascript?

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja Just as an example: Let's say I want to have a module that contains a font. For this module to work, the required TTF, WOFF, EOT, SVG, whatever-files need to be available as static files in the WAR directory somewhere, so the browser can download them. (Let's assume that instead packaging them in a DataURI is NOT possible)

Comment: Just put it in web-inf directory and manage your build path. It should work

Comment: @AbhijithNagaraja You mean create a web-inf directory inside the module? Or do I need to copy the static files manually into each project that uses the module?